# Games.RealtimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services, google-play-games

I create a room and it gets successfully made. And my `onRoomCreated` method gets called...

```
@Override
    public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
        mRoomId = room.getRoomId();
        Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(gApiClient, room, 2);
        startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
    }
```

Then in my `onActivityResult`...

```
Room r = data.getExtras().getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_ROOM);
ArrayList<String> invitees = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Participant p : r.getParticipants()) {
    invitees.add(p.getPlayer().getPlayerId()); //<---NULL POINTER!
}
```

I get that null pointer. Why?

EDIT: The android docs say this about the `getPlayer()` method...

*Returns the Player that this participant represents.* **Note that this may be null if the identity of the player is unknown. This occurs in automatching scenarios where some players are not permitted to see the real identity of others.**

That is why I am getting null, because my room is  through auto-matching.

Now the question is. **How can I create a turnbasedgame using only participant IDs? Not Player IDs**

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see what you are asking more clearly (my fault, not yours), here is how I do it:

(for clarification I use LibGDX, so may be some interface stuff you don't need, and I am still using GamesClient not the new API methods, but is for all intents the same)

First, the final call I look to start my game is onRoomConnected

```
@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int statusCode, Room room) {
    //dLog("onRoomConnected");
    mRoomCurrent = room;
    mParticipants = room.getParticipants();

    mMyID = room.getParticipantId(aHelper.getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayerId());
    //dLog("The id is " + mMyID);

    try {
        bWaitRoomDismissedFromCode = true;
        finishActivity(RC_WAITING_ROOM);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //dLog("would have errored out in waiting room");
    }

    //tell the Game the room is connected
    if (statusCode == GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
        theGameInterface.onRoomConnected(room.getParticipantIds(), mMyID, room.getCreationTimestamp() );
    } else {
        leaveRoom();
    }

}
```

So, now have all the participantIDs.. now in my Game code (where I sent that List of Ids), I sort the list of IDs so that in determining Player order, it is the same methodology for all Players.  First I build my opponents.

```
private void buildOpponents() {
    // this creates a new opponent with a View on the Stage()

    //sort the participants the same for all players
    sortParticipantIDs();

    for (String s : mParticipantIds) {
        if(s.contains(mMyID) || mMyID.contains(s)) continue;
        newOpponentWindow ow = new newOpponentWindow(s, MyAssetManager.getMySkin(), getStage());
        Opponent o = new Opponent(this, s);
        mapOpponents.put(s, o);
        o.setWindow(ow);
        getStage().addActor(ow);
    }


    setOpponentWindowPositions();


}
```

Then after some more setup I start Play and my first Time through, I have chosen that whoever is the top ID gets the honor of starting (I find this randomizes play enough, without having to do another method.. .but you can let the top ID do another method, and send that out to the other Players)  Note this checks over my Opponents to determine Starting Player if someone leaves the room later in the game as well.

```
private boolean determineIfStartingBidder() {
    Collections.sort(mParticipantIds);

    // now look thru list
    // if the number is mine then return true
    // if the number is not mine.. and opponent is not Out of Game or Disconnected.. then return false

    for (String s : mParticipantIds) {
        if(s.contains(mMyID) || mMyID.contains(s)){
            return true;
        }
        if(mapOpponents.get(s).getCurrentState() == currentState.DISCONNECTED || mapOpponents.get(s).getCurrentState()  == currentState.OUTOFGAME  ||
                            mapOpponents.get(s).getCurrentState() == currentState.LOSTGAME) {
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then in your game logic, just go through your ParticipantID list in whatever manner makes sense to pass the baton around!  This works well, since all the calls for passing messages require the ParticipantID, and are there for easy grab n go!

Prior Answer Below ------------------------------------------------

try

```
data.getParcelableExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_ROOM);
```

no need for the getExtras

Comment: D'oh! Misread, thought you were getting the null when requesting the room!  :)